# PHP Post request return 403 status

Tags: php, post, cakephp-2.0, http-status-code-403

when I submit a form with post method for add, it working fine but when I submit a form with post method for edit it returns 403 status that's why it failed to update. Can anyone explain the reason and solution for it?? (Cakephp framework used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please describe a bit more detailed and show, how are you handle add and edit methods?

Now I think that problem can be in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: If the problem is related to .htaccess then it also effect on add method but add is working fine